# PHP does lots of type checks slow down your code?

Tags: php, performance

I have a couple of classes that deal with objects, arrays and strings.

I was wondering what the impact on performance is to do type checks like:

is_object(), is_array() and is_string();

I use these quite a lot in my code.

In functions that are being called many thousands of times, is it better to assume the arguments passed is the correct type or check to prevent errors?

Is there any resource where you can have a look at the performance weight of php functions?

Comment: Test them. Measure performance with and without them. But probably: you're micro-optimizing

Comment: a `switch` on [gettype()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) may give you a quicker alternative, but you'd need to test performance to see if it helped

Comment: Probably type hints in the function signature would be a better alternative to begin with for arrays and objects, if that's a possibility.

Comment: Does it? Well, check [the implementation](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/type.c#php_is_type) and decide for yourself; it does however, involve a function call for each check.

Comment: I can't seem to find any thread or blog that has a decent chart to indicate the performance effect of different php functions. I will run some tests and benchmarks on the most commonly used functions during the next couple of weeks and compile a chart and post a link on this entry.

Comment: You could check [phpbench](http://phpbench.com/).

Comment: Thanks, something like phpbench is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out yourself.

Store the current time in milliseconds at the start of your script, run a loop which does a type check several thousand times, and compare the time at the end of your script with the time at the start of your script.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']` would contain that start value.

Comment: I will run some checks on the functions myself to see what performance impacts are made by removing the checks. Jack's comment in the answer above actually nailed what I wanted to know with the link to phpbench. If there are multiple ways of doing the same things, I want to get into the habit of using the methods that cost the least amount of performance, especially when writing code that will be called very very frequently.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use these checks.
You can save few milliseconds by avoid this checks. But if you didn't check it, there is a possibility to crash web page or some other issue.

So better to avoid those issues. If you are repeating any function related with database, it may cause a performance issue. But these small checks will not cause performance issue.

Lets think about it, before take your decision.